# How Does Implementing Property Works If We Have ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting

```
-(Business *) currentBusiness
{
    return _currentBusiness;
}

-(void) setCurrentBusiness:(Business *)currentBusiness
{
    _currentBusiness = currentBusiness;
}
```

Should it be just like that even for strong properties?

I mean with ARC we don't need to call retain release or whatever right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have declared that the property is backed by that ivar (easiest to do this via `@synthesize currentBusiness = _currentBusiness;`), yes, this is correct.

I'm assuming you want to do more in the accessor methods than assign/return though otherwise you wouldn't bother implementing them.

Comment: Yea I want to check that the property is called in the main thread.

Comment: That sounds messy, it might be worth asking a separate question to check if you are doing the right thing.

Comment: Actually, if you have implemented the getter and setter, as done here, `@synthesize` will do nothing.  The important thing is (in this case) is that the instance variable is also strong (which is the default).

Comment: @JeremyP synthesize  will declare the ivar with the appropriate properties. The question didn't indicate if the _currentBusiness ivar was declared or not, so I assumed not. And this way you don't have to match the ivar declaration with the property type.

Comment: `@synthesize` creates the accessors.  It will also declare the ivar, but if the accessors are provided "manually" using a different ivar, the `@synthesize` is redundant.

Comment: @JeremyP I think we're in agreement - I was using synthesize here as a method of declaring the ivar, nothing more. If you've implemented the accessors _and_ declared an ivar then yes, synthesize is redundant. But if you _haven't_ declared an ivar, synthesize is a nice way of doing so since it will match the definition (strong, weak etc) to your property. Better to do that than declare, in my opinion, since it saves you repeating yourself.